# Python Requests hanging when cURL is working just fine

Tags: python, curl, post, python-requests

I'm experiencing a strange issue where Python post Requests are hanging, while cURL post requests are working just fine. I'm making a request to the [NIH Reporter API](https://api.reporter.nih.gov/#!/Search/Projects).

Here's the Python code that keeps hanging:

```py
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
data = {
    "criteria": {
        "award_notice_date": {
            "from_date": "2022-06-22",
        }
    },
    "include_fields": [
        "ProjectNum",
        "ProjectTitle",
        "AbstractText",
        "AwardNoticeDate"
    ],
    "offset": 14500,
    "limit": 500,
    "sort_field": "award_notice_date"
}

response = requests.post('https://api.reporter.nih.gov/v2/projects/search', headers=headers, data=str(data))
```

And here's the cURL equivalent that works:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://api.reporter.nih.gov/v2/projects/search" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{'criteria': {'award_notice_date': {'from_date': '2022-06-22'}}, 'include_fields': ['ProjectNum', 'ProjectTitle', 'AbstractText', 'AwardNoticeDate'], 'offset': 14500, 'limit': 500, 'sort_field': 'award_notice_date'}"
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. I'm using **Python3** as well, and my Requests library is up-to-date with version 2.27.1.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  I get a 200 response returning JSON.  The JSON contains 500 records.  I see @OtherBarry's answer, which I agree with, but what they suggest doesn't seem to account for the hang you're experiencing.  Maybe because of that, I'm not getting back the right records, but I just copy/pasted your code into my IDE and it ran fine and returned a bunch of data.  The only thing I had to add was `import requests`.  If you want to know more about my setup, let me know.

Comment: @CryptoFool That is very strange. It just keeps hanging on my end. Any idea what might cause this? I know I'm not IP blocked. (Also, yeah I should've included the import statement in this question, but I had that already in my actual code)

Comment: If you're running the curl command on the same host, then I can't think of what would explain the difference.  It's possible it's a DNS thing.  You might want to try looking up the IP and using that instead of the host name in case the lookup is providing a different result in each case.  Things like that are possible.  If you do that, you'll likely get some kind of a certificate error, but it might tell you something anyway. Have you tried fixing the JSON issue?  Since I didn't, I don't expect that to help, but you could try it.  I'm using Requests 2.28.1, but your version should be fine.

Comment: @CryptoFool It appears that Requests is working, but taking a really long time (263 seconds). For now, I'll have to switch to a different library than requests and see if that works.

Comment: Hmm...strange.  Requests is a rockin' library.  I've done tons of things with it, and never had it do me wrong.  I doubt that it is the root of your problem.  You're not running a very memory-constrained environment, are you?   The response I get back is about 1.4MB.  On my Mac, it takes about 7 seconds.  I take it that when you run the Curl command, it returns very quickly.  It runs in a similar timeframe for me, about 5 seconds before it starts spewing stuff to the screen, but maybe 7-8 seconds once the full response has been printed.

Comment: @CryptoFool Yeah Requests has never done me wrong before either. I've used it for many applications before. It's just this one URL that's causing an issue. It's interesting that it took 7 seconds for you, because even that is a lot slower than it should be. I'll take a look at my disk and RAM memory to see if there are any issues there, but I highly doubt it tbh.

Comment: I agree.  What you're seeing makes no sense.  I'm at a friends.  Maybe their wifi sucks, lol :)

Comment: I experienced quite the same execution time between the curl command and the Python script.
It is a huge response > 1 MB.
May be from time to time the server takes longer to execute the request.

Comment: Do your requests transit through an HTTP proxy ? Just in case.

Comment: Do you confirm that in both cases you use the same host ? Even better that you run the curl command and the Python script from the same shell process ? All other things being equal.
Check that you don't have any environment variable in your shell that relates to proxy.
`env | grep -i proxy`

Comment: Try to get insight by enabling debug for python requests.
Look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Daenyth/b57f8522b388e66fcf3b).
Just had to replace `import httplib` by import `http.client as httplib` to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

`str(data)` is not the same as converting it to json. You need to use `data=json.dumps(data)` or use `json=data`. Using the latter will also add the  `"Content-Type": "application/json"` header for you, so you could skip that.